# Tests Fail During Deployment But Pass In Lower Enviroments

Tags: apex, unit-test

I suspect I know what the issue is here but I am hoping to get confirmation on it.

I ran a validation deployment to production and a few unit tests failed. They all pass in every lower environment.  I have a few classes that are calling a net new TestBuilder class that handles the construction of multistep metadata. This class does not exist in prod and the tests that rely on it are failing. It is in the deployment manifest so the issue is not a missing dependency.

I would expect the tests to pass because the builder class is included in the deployment. So I am wondering if 1. I just need to deploy this class first. 2. Or Remove the @Test annotation from the builder class?

sample of a failing test. It fails at the SOQL query on the user - "List has no rows for assignment to SOject". I tried to redeploy again with the @Test removed from the builder class but it still fails.

```
@IsTest
public with sharing class AccountClaimFederationIDAPITest {
    @TestSetup
    static void setUp(){
        TestBuilder builder = new TestDataBuilder.PodderUser();
        builder.build();
    }
    @IsTest
    static void idIsReturned(){

       //SOQL Error no rows returned*******
        User u = [SELECT Id, Related_Patient__c
        FROM User WHERE Username='fake5678bdj@podder.insulet'];
        u.FederationIdentifier = '12345';
        update u;

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
        RestResponse response = new RestResponse();
        request.addParameter('id', u.Related_Patient__c);
        request.httpMethod = 'GET';
        RestContext.request = request;
        RestContext.response = response;

        Test.startTest();
        AccountClaimFederationIDApi.getFederationId();
        Test.stopTest();

        Map<String, Object> responseObjectByStrings =
                (Map<String, Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(response.responseBody.toString());


        System.assertEquals('12345', responseObjectByStrings.get('federationId'),
        'Wrong Federation Id returned');
    }
```

Here is a sample builder class. These are all inner classes of a parent class with @IsTest annotation

````
 public class PodderUser implements TestBuilder {
        public void build() {
            List<Sequence__c> seqList = new List<Sequence__c>();
            Sequence__c s1 = new Sequence__c ();
            s1.Name = 'Physician_Id';
            s1.Autonumber__c = 4545.0;
            seqList.add(s1);

            Sequence__c s2 = new Sequence__c ();
            s2.Name = 'Patient_Id';
            s2.Autonumber__c = 4545.0;
            seqList.add(s2);
            insert seqList;

            Patient__c patient = (Patient__c) TestFactory.createSObject(new Patient__c());
            patient.Customer_ID__c = '12345';
            insert patient;
            Contact contact = (Contact) TestFactory.createSObject(new Contact(Patient__c = patient.Id));           
            insert contact;
            patient.IndividualContact__c = contact.Id;

            update patient;
            Profile p = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name LIKE '%PodderCentralCommunity'];
            User u = (User) TestFactory.createSObject(new User(ProfileId = p.Id, Username = 'fake5678bdj@podder.insulet'));
            u.ContactId = contact.Id;
            u.LastName = 'TestPodderUser';
            u.PortalRole = 'PersonAccount';

            insert u;
            update contact;
        }
    }
    ```
    enter code here
````

Comment: Without knowing what failed it is difficult to assist.

Comment: Of course, sorry about that. I will edit now.

Comment: (1) put a try-catch around `builder.build()` and in the catch block, do a system.assert(false,'testFactory failed:'+theException.getMessage());` (2) `So I am wondering if 1. I just need to deploy this class first. 2. Or Remove the @Test annotation from the builder class?` - NO and NO